# C# Linq expressions using the string value of a variable to set the column name in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following tuple:

```
Tuple<Expression<Func<Client, object>>, SortOrder>(x => x.ClientLastName, SortOrder.Descending)
```

In this case I know the entity - "Client" and you are using the "ClientLastName" column.. x => x.ClientLastName.

I want to change this to a generic version where entity is T and I supply the column name using the value keyValue.Key... eg keyValue.Key in this case = "ClientLastName".

I tried this:

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, SortDirection> keyValue in sortItems) {
            tupleList.Add(new Tuple<Expression<Func<T, object>>, SortDirection>(x => keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value));
        };
```

Even though T is Client and keyValue.Key is the column name "ClientLastName"

[image]

it doesnt work.. It simply comes up with:

[image]

It is not replacing the value of keyValue.Key and instead is using the actual value..

saw [this answer by sstan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38799136/5750758) in which he used

```
d => "value" == (string)typeof(Demo).GetProperty(propname).GetValue(d))
```

which I changed to:

```
Tuple<Expression<Func<T, object>>, SortDirection>(x => (string)typeof(T).GetProperty(keyValue.Key).GetValue(x), keyValue.Value));
```

Which didnt work.

How do I do this `x => x.keyValue.Key` where it replaces the `keyValue.Key` with its string value and I can have the equivalent of `x => x.ClientLastName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically build the desired expression and pass it to the tuple

```
Tuple<Expression<Func<T, object>>, SortDirection> BuildTuple<T>(KeyValuePair<string, SortDirection> keyValue) {
    var type = typeof(T);
    var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(keyValue.Key);
    var direction = keyValue.Value;

    // T x
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
    // x.Property
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo);
    // T x => x.Property
    var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(property, parameter);

    return new Tuple<Expression<Func<T, object>>, SortDirection>(expression, direction);
}
```

Generic version of the loop becomes

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, SortDirection> keyValue in sortItems) {
    var tuple = BuildTuple<T>(keyValue);
    tupleList.Add(tuple);
};
```

assuming it is within a generic method.