# Create a dynamic linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model in my application that looks like:

```cs
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Upn { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

And currently I'm doing a select with this extension method:

```cs
public static IQueryable<PersonViewModel> SelectBasic(this IQueryable<PersonViewModel> personViewModels)
{
    return personViewModels.Select(p => new PersonViewModel
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        DisplayName = p.DisplayName,
        Upn = p.Upn
    });
}

// This is used like 
dbContext.People.AsQueryable().SelectBasic();
// That would be the same as dbContext.People.AsQueryable().Select(p => new Person{....});
```

I would like to convert the select to a dynamic statement, like this. But I have no clue on how to create the Linq expression to do so.

```cs
public static IQueryable<PersonViewModel> SelectProperties(this IQueryable<PersonViewModel> personViewModels,
    string propertyNames = "Id,DisplayName,Upn")
{
    var properties = propertyNames.Split(',');
    return personViewModels.Select(p => new PersonViewModel
    {
        // Select only the properties in the properties array
    });
}

// Used like
dbContext.People.AsQueryable().SelectProperties("Id,Upn");
```

I've found the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace, but the documentation hard to find. And I cannot find any samples about it. Note: I don't want an anonymous type because this is what will be returned by an dotnet core 3 web api.

I’m trying to do a Select on dynamic parameters (user specified). I’m not trying to have a dynamic filter.

Comment: I don't even understand your code.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I've tried to make the sample code better.

Comment: My main question is why? I don't see any advantage of your extension method over a normal `.Select`?

Comment: I guess the string can change at runtime? Is that what your trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Liam that is exactly what i'm trying to achieve!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use string variable in LINQ lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799079/use-string-variable-in-linq-lambda-expression)

Comment: @Liam, that doesn’t answer my question it’s about filtering on a dynamic property, I’m just looking for a way to dynamic filter the properties returned, not a way to filter the collection based on a dynamic property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the original select

```
personViewModels.Select(p => 
    new PersonViewModel {
        Id = p.Id,
        DisplayName = p.DisplayName,
        Upn = p.Upn
    }
);
```

as a guide to the expression tree that needs to be built for the desired `Select` expression

#### Reference [Creating Expression Trees by Using the API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx#Anchor_1)

Note the comments associated with the following code to get an idea of how the select expression is built dynamically

```
public static IQueryable<PersonViewModel> SelectProperties(
    this IQueryable<PersonViewModel> personViewModels,
    string propertyNames = "Id,DisplayName,Upn") {

    var properties = propertyNames.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var type = typeof(PersonViewModel);
    // p =>
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    // create bindings for initialization
    var bindings = properties
        .Select(s => {
            // property
            var property = type.GetProperty(s);
            // original value 
            var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
            // set value "Property = p.Property"
            return Expression.Bind(property, propertyExpression);
        }
    );
    // new PersonViewModel()
    var newViewModel = Expression.New(type);
    // new PersonViewModel { Property1 = p.Property1, ... }
    var body = Expression.MemberInit(newViewModel, bindings);
    // p => new PersonViewModel { Property1 = p.Property1, ... }
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<PersonViewModel, PersonViewModel>>(body, parameter);

    return personViewModels.Select(selector);
}
```

#### Reference [Expression Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Your comments in the sample code are really helpfull. This was the solution to my problem!

Comment: Here is the generic version of the code https://gist.github.com/svrooij/8fef0289385257722fd344e79ad2e84a